# Search Message Extension Works in Teams but not in Outlook

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a teams application which includes a bot, which works across Teams, Outlook and Microsoft 365. I am adding search messaging extensions to it. The search messaging extension works well within Teams, but in Outlook I receive an error message "Something went wrong".

[image: Error message in outlook]

Looking at the traffic via Fiddler provides an unhelpful error message:
[image: Unhelpful Fiddler error message]

Looking at my webserver traffic I don't believe this request is ever reaching my bot.

I suspect the issue may be to do with the bot channels. [This guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/m365-apps/extend-m365-teams-message-extension?tabs=existing-app%2Csearch-based-message-extension#prerequisites) implies I need to add the "Microsoft 365 Extensions" channel. However this does not appear as an available channel for my bot via the Azure Bot Services portal:

[image: Microsoft 365 Extensions Channel is not in the list]

My bot does not appear in the [Bot Framework portal](https://dev.botframework.com/) which the guide mentions as an alternative to Azure Bot Services Portal.

**Additional Info:**

- The rest of the Teams app (Tabs) does appear and work in outlook, only the message extension fails.
- The Teams app manifest.json file is at version 1.16
- The bot "Schema Transformation Version" is at 1.3
- All the suggested client ID's have already been added to the "Expose an API" section of the app registration

[image: Schema Transformation Version]

[image: manifest.json Version]

[image: ClientIDs]

Comment: Could you please let us know whether these prerequisites are met - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/m365-apps/prerequisites

Comment: Thanks for your response Dinesh. All those requirements are met except installation of the visual studio code teams toolkit. I am developing in Visual Studio Community so that is not possible for me. My bot is based on this example: 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/search-commands/define-search-command?tabs=Teams-toolkit%2Cdotnet

https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/msgext-search/csharp

Comment: Could you please update the app manifest schema version 1.13 or later and update client Id in App registration. Please refer this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/m365-apps/extend-m365-teams-message-extension?tabs=existing-app%2Caction-based-message-extension#update-your-app-manifest

Comment: Thanks Dinesh, I believe I've already fulfilled these requirements. I've added some information to my question in the "Additional Info" section. The app itself consists of a tabs and a bot, the tab aspect of the application works well in outlook (and teams) it's only search message extension which does not work in Outlook.

Comment: Do you know if the outlook or Microsoft 365 channel should be available to add or is that a red herring?